# ~ signal in pandas.Dataframe.loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm studying machine learning using this Kaggle notebook [Exploring features - Python notebook using data from Santander Customer Satisfaction](https://www.kaggle.com/cast42/exploring-features)

And in this notebook there is this command:

`train.loc[~np.isclose(train.var38, 117310.979016), 'var38'].value_counts()`

What does mean the `~` signal inside the `loc` operator?

I know what the command does as a whole, otherwise the `~` signal.

Comment: `~` is the bitwise not operator. Taken as a whole, that `loc` statement means: select values in the `var38` column that are NOT close to 117310.979016

Comment: Nice!
Is there a negation signal?

Comment: That `~` is the negation signal